# How to add a SWT DateTime control to a JPanel?

Tags: datetime, swt, jpanel

I have a JDialog that contains two JPanels.  I want to add a DateTime picker to the JPanel.  I've been trying to use SWT DateTime, which I can get to run; however, it displays outside my JDialog.  I can't figure out a way to embed the DateTime into the JPanel.  I've tried `jpanelname.add(datetimename)`, but Eclipse balks, wanting a "component".  SWT sure seems difficult to integrate (probably just me!).  Perhaps another source for a DateTime picker would be easier to implement.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for the [SWT_AWT bridge](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Swing-SWT-Integration/index.html), specifically `new_Shell(Display, Canvas)`.

Take a look at the javadoc [here](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/awt/SWT_AWT.html).